# Expandable listview display child objects

Tags: android, listview, object, expandablelistview

I want to give my adapter an object that has key value of object and arraylist of objects.

For instance

```
    Ingredient beef = new Ingredient("beef");
    Ingredient cheese = new Ingredient("cheese");
    Ingredient salsa = new Ingredient("salsa");
    Ingredient tortilla = new Ingredient("tortilla");
    Ingredient ketchup = new Ingredient("ketchup");
    Ingredient bun = new Ingredient("bun");





    Recipe taco = new Recipe("taco", Arrays.asList(beef, cheese, salsa, tortilla));
    Recipe quesadilla = new Recipe("quesadilla", Arrays.asList(cheese, tortilla));
    Recipe burger = new Recipe("burger", Arrays.asList(beef, cheese, ketchup, bun));

    recipes = Arrays.asList(taco, quesadilla, burger);
```

Now how would I get my expandable adapter to show the group heading for example taco, quesadilla, and burger. Then when expanded it shows the ingredients for each? Both need to be objects because the next step would be in the ingredients be able to select and deselect certain ingredients and pass that as a new object.

My adapter

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private ArrayList<Recipe> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<Recipe, List<String>> _listDataChild;

//Keep track of checks
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> check_states = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Recipe> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<Recipe, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_create_team_child, null);
    }

    final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxChild);

    chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                                if (isChecked == true){
                                                    //_listDataChild.get(childPosition)
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
    );

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.teamNameChild);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_create_team, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.teamName);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(_listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getName());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Recipe Object:

```
public class Recipe implements ParentListItem {

    private String mName;
    private List<Ingredient> mIngredients;

    public Recipe(String name, List<Ingredient> ingredients) {
        mName = name;
        mIngredients = ingredients;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    @Override
    public List<?> getChildItemList() {
        return mIngredients;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInitiallyExpanded() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ingredient Object

```
public class Ingredient {

private String mName;

public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public void setIsSelected(boolean isSelected) {
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}

public String getmName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setmName(String mName) {
    this.mName = mName;
}

private boolean isSelected;

public Ingredient(String name) {
    mName = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}
```

}

Comment: Extend `BaseExpandableListAdapter`, override `getGroupView` for heading and `getChildView` for ingredients.  Give it a go and if you're still having problems, post your adapter code here and we'll have a look at it.

Comment: @krislarson I have updated my question by adding my code in.

Comment: your code is not optimal, but it seems to work unless i missed something, what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: @youzking what would make it optimal? I'm still a student so I hope to write optimal and efficient code one day.

However the problem is once I have added my recipes w/ ingredients. In my adapter how do I separate it out. 

I can get the recipes in a list but how to I "parse" out the ingredients and display that in the child lilst.

Comment: for example :
`if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`
your are creating the infalInflater each time convertView is null, it is more convenient to create it once on constructeur (as a class member) and use it above.

-for each item you are calling `convertView.findViewById(...)` , layout inflation take some time to complete, to have a more smooth list view use view holder pattern (just google for it, many tutorials are available)

Comment: you are using `private HashMap<Recipe, List<String>> _listDataChild;` for children, you could not use a member to hold children at all since you can access a Recipe's  Ingredients through Recipe class, you can add methods to return a child at a specific position, or the number of Ingredients of a Recipe...